# Javascript date string formatting

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript dates:

```
var d1 = new Date(1886937778);
var d2 = new Date(1536937222);
```

I would link the difference between d1 and d2 to be displayed in a format such as "1 hour 5 minutes" or "2 months 10 hours" etc.  Is there a library that does something like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you should take a look at Moment.js

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-time-ago

Comment: This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

I would use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) with the [moment-precise-range plug-in](https://github.com/codebox/moment-precise-range)

The `moment.preciseDiff()` function will give you your difference which you can then format however you like using `.format()`